# Three line break chart

Tags: r, forex

I would like to construct a [three line break chart](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school%3achart_analysis%3athree_line_break) in R, and was wondering if there is already a package that could be used to perform the calculations required to draw the chart, or even better do both, i.e. plot and calculate.

I have tried searching on rseek.org and have also had a look at some of the financial packages. No luck so far.

Comment: For potential responders - http://www.stator-afm.com/three-line-break.html seems to give a good description down the bottom as to what this chart actually shows. Sounds simple enough.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like this, but it would be a good addition to quantmod/TTR.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest code around, but it might be useful as a base for further developing. `closeval` represents some dummy closing price values.

```
closeval <- c(50,48,47,47,59,60,57,48,42,50)
cvlag <- c(NA,head(closeval,-1))
dset <- data.frame(closeval,cvlag)
dset <- subset(dset,closeval!=cvlag | is.na(cvlag))
dset$cvlag2 <- c(NA,NA,head(dset$closeval,-2))

plot(dset$closeval)

dset <- dset[2:nrow(dset),]
dset$maxlag <- apply(dset[c("cvlag","cvlag2")],1,max,na.rm=TRUE)
dset$minlag <- apply(dset[c("cvlag","cvlag2")],1,min,na.rm=TRUE)

dset$change <- (dset$closeval-dset$cvlag) > 0

dset$keyval[dset$change==FALSE] <- dset$minlag[dset$change==FALSE]
dset$keyval[dset$change==TRUE] <- dset$maxlag[dset$change==TRUE]

segments(
2:(nrow(dset)+1),
dset$closeval,
2:(nrow(dset)+1),
dset$keyval,
col=ifelse(dset$change==TRUE,"red","blue")
)
```

[image]